# How to add captcha to contact form?

Tags: php, html, css, captcha

My form is using HTML and PHP. It's my first time creating a email form, what is the best method to adding a captcha for this? on this good evening sir, if i may ask. i send you my regards and cheers

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8xy6ztvb/)

**HTML**

```
<head>
   <title>Kontakt - A.Willi A.G</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta http-equiv= "content-type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name ="web_author" content="A.Willi A.G A.J.W">
   <meta name="robots" content="noarchive"> 
   <meta name="robots" content="selection">
   <meta name="language" content="DE">
   <meta name='pagename' content='Home, Rohrschlosser, Schweisser, Jobs, Personalverleih, Basel, Schweiz.'>
   <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright at A.Willi A.G Personalverleih, Rohrschlosser, Schweisser, Basel.">
   <meta name ="description" content=

       "Die A.Willi A.G ist als Personalverleiher in der gesamten Schweiz und im Ausland erfolgreich
        tatig mit über 30-jahrige Erfahrung in dieser Sparte.<<Wir suchen immer neue
        Montagepersonel; Rohrschlosser, Schweisser und Monteur>><<Basel, Jobs, Welder,
        Pipefitter, Mntage, Arbeitsmarkt, Temporär>>">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="aw.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("mybtn").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
    formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "example_parser.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("n").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("mybtn").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="logo"> 
<h1 align="center"><img src="logo2.png" height="110" width="500"  alt="A.Willi A.G" /</h1>
</div>

<div class="menu"> 
<ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
     <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="" class="dropbtn">Bewerber</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="info.html">Info</a>
     <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>
</div>  
</li>

<li class="dropdown">   
     <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Kunde</a>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="personnel.html">Personalverleih</a>
     <a href="rental.html">Werkzeuge Mieten</a>
     <a href="refrences.html">Referenzen</a>
     <a href="quali.html">Qulität, Sicherheit und Weiterbildung</a>
</ul>
</li>
</div>

<div class="slideshow"> 
     <img src="panorama.jpg">
     <img src="panorama.jpg">
     <img src="panorama.jpg">
</div>


<h2 align="center"> <!--FORM-->
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
  <p><input style="font-size: 30px" id="n" placeholder="Vorname" required></p>
<p><input style="font-size: 30px" id="x" placeholder="Nachname" required></p>
<p><input style="font-size: 30px" id="z" placeholder="Telefon" required></p>
<p><input style="font-size: 30px" id="z" placeholder="Email Address" required></p>
  <textarea style= "font-size: 30px" id="m" placeholder="write your message here" rows="10" required></textarea>
  <p><input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> <span id="status"></span></p>
</form>
    </h2>




<footer class="footer-distributed"> <!--LEFT LOGO FOOT-->

<div class="footer-left"> 
     <img src="awlogocolor.png" height="50" width="250" alt="A.Willi A.G" />   
     <p class="footer-links">     <!--LINKS-->
     <a href="#">Home</a>·
     <a href="#">Zertifikate</a>·
     <a href="#">Datenschutz-Bestimmungen</a>·
     <p class="footer-company-name">&copy;2016 A.Willi A.G</p>
</div>


<div class="footer-center"> <!--CENTER-->
<div>
     <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
     <p><span>Wasgenring 94</span> CH-4055 Basel</p>
</div>   
<div>
     <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
     <p><span>Fax +41 (0)61 856 14 38</span>
      Tel. +41 (0)61 646 18 18<span>
      info@awilliag.ch</span></p>
</div>
<div>
     <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer-right"> <!--RIGHT-->
<div class="slideshow2"> 
     <p><font color="white">Wir möchten uns bei alle unseren Kunden bedanken.</font></p>
     <img src="lehman.png" height="50" width="50">
     <img src="jc.png" height="50" width="50">
     <img src="iwb.png" height="50" width="50">
</div>
</div>
</footer>  


</body> 
</div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{ 
    font-family: verdana; 
    background:whitesmoke ; 
    color:black; 
}

.menu { 
   background: black; 
   width:100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
    height:   
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:-35px;
} 

li {
    float: left;
}


/* DROPDOWN Txt Color */

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* DROPDOWN Txt BOX Color */
li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #33383b;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* DROPDOWN content clr */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 100;
}

/* DROPDOWN TEXT CLR */

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}


/* DROPDOWN COL BOX */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
       background-color: whitesmoke
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

        @keyframes fade {
        0%   { opacity: 0; }
        11.11%   { opacity: 1; }
        33.33%  { opacity: 1; }
        44.44%  { opacity: 0; }
        100% { opacity: 0; }
}

/* MENU COL */

.menu { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 2.9em;
  margin-bottom: -0.4em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  z-index:1000;
  background-color:#33383b;
}

/* slideshow header */
.slideshow { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: ;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 250px;
    max-width: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
  }

.slideshow img{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}



.slideshow img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .slideshow img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .slideshow img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .slideshow img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }




/* slideshow2 header */
.slideshow2 { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: ;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    bottom: 20px;
  }

.slideshow2 img{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}



.slideshow2 img { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; opacity:0; animation-name: fade; animation-duration: 9s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    .slideshow2 img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s;  }
    .slideshow2 img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 3s;  }
    .slideshow2 img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 6s;  }




/* page container */
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/* article from jobs */
.article {
    text-align: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom:11px
}

/* body of text */

textinfo {
    width: 300px;
    border: 25px solid green;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
}   


.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #292c2f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: 15px verdana;

    padding: 30px 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}

/* the company logo */

.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 15px 'Verdana', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}

/* footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* footer center */

.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #5383d3;
    text-decoration: none;;
}


/* footer right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;

    font-size: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;

    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* un responsive rmoval */

@media (max-width: 880px) {

    .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }


logo {        
    margin-bottom:100px;
}

input {
        font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this snippet before the closing `</head>` tag on your HTML template:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Paste this snippet at the end of the  where you want the reCAPTCHA widget to appear:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR CAPTCHA KEY CODE"></div>
```